# Maximizing a form, and disabling user to resize the form

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize, maximize-window

I am trying to create a form that is maxed out, without allowing the user to resize it. I tried to maximize the `FormWindowState`, and remove the minimize and maximize button. By setting `this.MimimumSize` and `this.MaximumSize` to `this.Size` (the maximized size), this should account to a maximized form.

Yet, when I run it, the form becomes a really small square. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

```
public partial class Testscherm : Form
{
    public Testscherm()
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `InitializeComponent()` first, *then* add any statements which changes attributes/properties of the form. Otherwise, the designer generated code may undo any of changes you did beforehand.

Second, `Form.Size` does not deliver the form's size in maximized state. You could instead iterate over

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

then get the actual screen size along the lines of

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.First().WorkingArea.Size;
```

and assign it to `this.Size`;

Another problem here is, as soon as you assign this, `this.MaximizeBox = false`, Winforms forbids `WindowState` to be `FormWindowState.Maximized`. This is  obviously "by design". What you probably want here is to use

```
 this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

which does not only remove the maximum and minimum buttons, but also the close button. If you need such button, consider to add your own close button to the window.

Putting this all together gives

```
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Size = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.First().WorkingArea.Size;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
```

But: are you sure it is a good idea what you are trying there? How will this behave on a machine with two monitors of different resolution for example? It may be ok for a program which uses specific hardware and works as a dedicated software which takes over the machine exclusively (something like a [Kiosk mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software)). Note the window may still be moved around using certain `Win-<Key>` keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense! Yet, when I set the MaximumSize and Minimumsize after InitializeComponent(), the form is not maximized again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for giving me some insight into the actual logic behind it, and get me thinking on how to properly structure this, rather than giving the straight up solution. This will help me in my understanding of C# fundamentals !